# Why this permissions denied issue with a shell script inside an Applescript writing to my desktop folder?

Tags: macos, shell, permissions, applescript

```
set theAddresses to {"Address, Name, Counter" & return & "A@b.com, A, 1"}
set theFile to (path to desktop folder as text) & "test.csv"
do shell script "echo " & quoted form of (theAddresses as text) & " > " & quoted form of theFile
delay 1
do shell script "open " & quoted form of theFile
```

I get permissions error:

> **error** "sh: Alwnick:Users:aleith1:Desktop:test.csv: Permission denied"

I tried to replicate this as a line command in bash terminal but I can't write string literal into a file with the " > " command. Nor can I find a manual for ">" fo syntax for literals. Yet echo seems to use a literal okay, despite the permissions issue.

Where should I change the permissions, in the shell script or manually in OSX Finder or in bash? What permissions should the Desktop Folder have? I tried to invoke "sudo echo…" but no gain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to write to

```
Alwnick:Users:aleith...blah...blah...something
```

That is the Applescript version of the filename, and it is unintelligible to the shell and Unix command line utilities - basically it uses colons in places of slashes.

You need to use the "POSIX form" of the path, see [here](http://www.satimage.fr/software/en/smile/external_codes/file_paths.html)

Comment: Thanks, gee was just reading about POSIX today and forgot. Was using someone elses code :-)